# jQuery datatable adding custom TR based on returned data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a jQuery's datatable which gets filled up with server side data like this:

```
    "columns": [
                      {
                          "targets": -1,
                          "data": "ImageURL",
                          "name": "Title",
                          "render": function (data, type, row) {
                              return '<td><div class="tableimage"><img src="' + data + '"/></div></td>';  //'<td><img src=' + data + '></td>';
                          }
                      },
               {
                   "data": "Title",
                   "name": "Title",
                   "render": function (data, type, row) {

                       return '<td>' + data + '</td>';
                   }
               },
                   {
                       "data": "CurrentPrice",
                       "name": "CurrentPrice",
                       "render": function (data, type, row) {

                           return '<td>$ ' + data + '</td>';
                       }
            },
  ]
```

And this is fine, each column gets generated and rendered in my browser like this:

```
<tr>
// generated td's here...
<tr>
```

Now my question here is whether I can generate a custom tr tag with specially added class?

Something like this:

```
<tr class="myclassNameGoesHere">
</td>
```

Is this doable via server side data processing & jquery's datatables ?

P.S. I tried something like this:

```
$(row).addClass("alert-danger");
 // or                              
row.className = "alert-danger";
```

But neither of these worked... :/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to return td tags in render functions, datatables automatically created td tags for you.

So,

```
return '<td>' + data + '</td>';
```

would become

```
 return data;
```

Now, to answer your question, use [**createdRow**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback provided by datatables.

Like,

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      $(row).addClass( 'alert-danger' );
  }
} );
```